# Best practice for email required in django-rest-auth

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

What is the best (easiest?) way to make it a requirement to have an email only for user registration and not make username a requirement in the django-rest-auth framework?

Would I need to write a new User Serializer, for example? Is there a flag setting that I can set True or False to turn off or on this requirement instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write your own `AbstractUser` and `BaseUserManager` classes. Fortunately [it's pretty simple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), add something like this to your app's models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    # This tells Django that this field is absolutely important...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # ...and username is now optional because it doesn't show up here!
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must provide an e-mail address')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        account = self.create_user(email, password)

        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account
```

Next, tell Django that this model is your **project's** new `User` class. Add the following to your `settings.py` file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apiapp.Account'
```

Once that's done, just migrate:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

From that point on new users will be represented by this new model (you'd have to handle migrations manually), including anywhere you might use `self.request.user`!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the advantage of writing my AbstractUser and Manager classes over changing the following allauth settings:   

`ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None  
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True  
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False  
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'  `

Comment: Actually, I'm totally confused. With these allauth settings, ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None , etc., in the Django admin, under Add User, it says username is still required.

Comment: I think using a custom AbstractUser makes the most sense because you don't have to juggle relationships because `auth.model.User` and whatever other `Model` you've written to track user profile info. I can't speak to `allauth` though.